# Create a time-to-event kaplan meier plot with multiple events in R

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, survival

I want to create a kaplan meier plot. Most tutorials focus on a binary survival (death/survival), but in my case, I would like to plot the time to an event (1,2,3 times switch in medication). Is this possible?

Here is some example data to illustrate my point.

```
library (data.table)
data <- data.table( ID                   = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,12,12,13,14,14,14,15,15,16),
                    episode              = c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1), 
                    time_till_next_ep    = c(0,5,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,4,14,0,0,0,0,6,17,0,9,0,0,4,9,0,8,0))
```

First, we have a variable indicating the participant `ID`.

Then we have a variable indicating the medication `episode`. This means if a participant takes a certain type of medication within a certain timeframe. Most participants only take the medication once (episode=1), but several take the medication again a second (episode = 2) or third time (episode = 3).

The time between the episodes is calculated in days in the `time_till_next_ep` variable. Since there is no time between episodes for the 1st case, there are a lot of zeroes in the data.

I want to create a Kaplan-Meier-Graph: on the x-axis the time until the next episode and on the y-axis the number of episodes. With every new episode beginning for a patient, the graph would go one step down.

I've tried using the survival package to create this, but it does not seem to be working

```
library(survival)

    S_input <- Surv(time = data[,as.numeric(time_till_next_ep)], event = data[,episode])
    
    km_fit <- survfit(S_input ~ 1, 
                  data = data, 
                  type = "kaplan-meier")
    
    km_fig <- ggsurvplot(km_fit, 
                         data,
                         tables.theme = theme_cleantable())
```

If I check the input `S_input` data, it seems to have added questionmarks next to my time data

```
> S_input 
 [1]  0   5?  0   0   0   0   0   8?  0   4? 14?  0   0   0   0   6? 17?  0   9?  0   0   4?  9?  0   8?  0
```

And the summary data is not really informative:

```
> summary(km_fit)
Call: survfit(formula = S_input ~ 1, data = data, type = "kaplan-meier")

10 observations deleted due to missingness 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
    0     16      16        0     NaN           NA           NA
```

The message says that 10 observations are deleted due to missingness, these seem to be my 10 switches in medication.

Lastly, I get the following error when plotting: `Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`

Am I even using the survival analysis correctly in my case or is this really reserved for binary data?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, your setting cannot be represented in a 'simple' survival model in which subjects die/exit over time due to a unique cause, because there are recurrent events happening in sequence.
I think that your setting is best represented in a multistate model, which allows you to explicitly model transitions between events and account for the time intercurrent between them. Here is [an excellent tutorial](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/44/1/324/654595) you can refer to on how to model recurrent events. Currently I cannot provide you with a worked example for your specific case, but some code and data are reported in the supplementary material.

Regarding the Kaplan-Meier itself, I don't think you can plot it without reporting the 'survival share' on one of the axes. And Kaplan-Meier plots are straightforward only in all-cause mortality studies.
Multistate models give you access to other tools, such as transition probabilities, to plot the risk of experiencing subsequent events.